# Formatting ng-init text inside input tag - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am having `ng-init` defined in my `input` tag. I would like to have this input in the specified format with line breaks.

I tried using `<pre>` tags and `white-space:pre-line` property too. But this seems not to get sorted.

```
<div style="font-family: Poppins !important;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;top:35%; position:absolute; width: 100%; background:transparent !important; margin-bottom:0rem !important">
   <input class="form-control"
      id="volunteerCallTextId" type="text" placeholder="Volunteer Call Text"
      ng-model="volunteerCallText"
      ng-init="volunteerCallText ='Hello, may I speak to (Insured).  Hi (Mr., Mrs. Etc), my name is _________.  
      I am with xxx Insurance and am calling you about the recent fire/flood/weather event in_____.  
      We are calling to check and see if your family is safe and let you know that xxx is here for you.   
      I want to let you know that we have emergency claims locations set up at: (use locations below).  
      Or you can call our Claims center at 888....Please be aware that.....'" 
      style="width: 75em; height:25em; white-space:pre-line" />
</div>
```

**Format expected:**

> Hello, may I speak to (Insured).  Hi (Mr., Mrs. Etc), my name is
>   _________.
>   I am with xxx Insurance and am calling you about the recent fire/flood/weather event in_____.   We are calling to check and
>   see if your family is safe and let you know that xxx is here for you.
>   I want to let you know that we have emergency claims locations set up
>   at: (use locations below).   Or you can call our Claims center at
>   888....Please be aware that.....

Can someone suggest what could be done?

Comment: are you trying to display the text or set the value of input ?

Comment: @MSD - Display the text

Comment: so ng init is not necessary right? and why display the text in an input filed?

Comment: I want this to be editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it can be done in input box or not but it works like this in textarea please try and let me know if t helps you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    
    <div ng-app="" >
    
    <div style="font-family: Poppins !important;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;top:35%; position:absolute; width: 100%; background:transparent !important; margin-bottom:0rem !important">
       <textarea class="form-control"
          id="volunteerCallTextId" style="width:75em; height:25em; white-space: pre-wrap;" type="text" placeholder="Volunteer Call Text"
          ng-model="volunteerCallText"
          ng-init="volunteerCallText ='Hello, may I speak to (Insured).  Hi (Mr., Mrs. Etc), my name is _________ \n\
I am with xxx Insurance and am calling you about the recent fire/flood/weather event in_____.\n\
We are calling to check and see if your family is safe and let you know that xxx is here for you.I want to let you know that we have emergency claims locations set up at: (use locations below).Or you can call our Claims center at 888....Please be aware that.....'"
           ></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Woule be helpful if your clarify this other doubt. With this `ng-init`, can I include any dynamic object in the __________ area? i.e, the values which I get from `scope` variable in controller?

Comment: Yes ... just use the volunteerCallText to assiign new values

Comment: i would sugggest you show the static text in <h1> or <p> tag and only use input box for values whch you need  dynamically